# C formatting i/o fscanf (Novice)

Tags: c, scanf

I have a file with some data in it, a few header lines, and some data labels. 
I want to extract the data and assign it to variables. 
I am skipping the two header lines (of unknown length) with:

```
char   buffer[100]; 
fgets(buffer, 100, cp);
fgets(buffer, 100, cp);
```

The labels on the data read like

```
this datum =0.444
this other =6.666
```

The actual data always start on column 12.
I am reading these lines with successive fscanf calls

```
float  x1;
float  x2;
char label[11];
fscanf (filename, " %11s %f ", label, x1);
fscanf (filename, " %11s %f ", label, x2);
```

etc.

This isn't working. I'm getting zero for all of my values.

I also get compilation warnings about '%f' expects argument of type 'float *' but argument 4 has type 'double'.

I know how to do this in FORTRAN but have never written a C program before. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(in addition to changes suggested by deepmax):

You are using the specifier `%s`, which reads the string until the first whitespace, even when you specify the length (11). You are specifying MAX length, but it will still bail out early if it reads a space (the one after "this").

I would use this format:

```
fscanf (filename, " %*[^=]=%f ", &x1);
```

Which means: "Scan and discard all characters until you find the `'='` character. Then scan that character. Then scan a float and write it to x1.

Comment: Yes, that `*` discards. Better solution than mine. +1

Comment: That worked. I can now prune any references to the label as well.

Answer (score 3):

You must pass a pointer to `x1` and `x2`, to `fscanf`. It makes possible for `fscanf` to change the value of them.

```
fscanf (filename, " %11s %f ", label, &x1);
fscanf (filename, " %11s %f ", label, &x2);
```

To capture the float, I have a simple workaround:

```
char tmp[1000];
fscanf(filename, "%[^=]=%f", tmp, &x1);
```

I myself, don't like that `tmp` thing. It can be written in a better way.

Comment: Thanks! that got rid of the compilation errors, but the data aren't read in properly (still getting zeroes.)